# How to find the records with same key value assigned to multiple values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data like the following,

- Student | Subject
- A  |            Language
- A  |          Math
- B   |      Science
- A     |    Arts
- C      |   Biology
- B        | History

and so on...

I want to fetch the students who has same name but enrolled in two different subjects Language & Math only.

I tried to use the query:

```
$group:{
    _id:"$student",
    sub:"{$addToSet:"$subject"}
},
$match:{
     sub:{$in:["Language","Math"]}
}
```

But I am getting no documents to preview in MongoDB **Compass**. I am working in a VM machine, Compass is *able to group only biology, history, science, arts only* **but not** able to *group language and math*. I wanted to get `A` as my output.

Thanks in loads.

**The collection data and the expected output:**

```
{ Student:"A", Subject:"Language" }, 
{ Student:"A", Subject:"Math" }, 
{ Student:"B", Subject:"Science" }, 
{ Student:"A", Subject:"Arts" }, 
{ Student:"C", Subject:"Biology" }, 
{ Student:"B", Subject:"History" }
```

*I am looking to get A as my output.*

Comment: Please, can you share what the student document looks like?

Comment: {Student:"A",Subject:"Language"},
{Student:"A",Subject:"Math"},
{Student:"B",Subject:"Science"},
{Student:"A",Subject:"Arts"},
{Student:"C",Subject:"Biology"},
{Student:"B",Subject:"History"}

I am looking to get A as my output

Comment: Is the `_id` of these documents the student name? If so, then that's not going to work. `_id` must be unique in the collection.

Comment: If there are multiple students taking both "Math" and "Language" only, you should get all those students right?

Comment: @OTZ i need to get the **students with same name** taking Math and Languagei.e., A has taken two subjects math and language so need to get A's name in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an Aggregation operator, [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/). The [$in (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator is used to check an array for *one* value only. I think you are thinking of [$in (query operator)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html)..

**The Query:**

```
db.student_subjects.aggregate( [
{ $group: {
        _id: "$student",
        studentSubjects: { $addToSet: "$subject" }
   } 
},
{ $project: { 
       subjectMatches: { $setIsSubset: [ [ "Language", "Math" ], "$studentSubjects" ] }
   }
},
{ $match: { 
       subjectMatches: true
   } 
},
{ $project: { 
       matched_student: "$_id", _id: 0 
   } 
}
] )
```

**The Result:**

```
{ "matched_student" : "A" }
```

**NOTES:**

If you replace `[ "Language", "Math" ]` with `[ "History" ]`, you will get the result: `{ "matched_student" : "B" }`.

You can also try and see other [set operators (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-expression-operators), like the `$allElementsTrue`. Use the best one that suits your application.

---

**[ EDIT ADD ]**

Sample data for `student_subjects` collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "student" : "A", "subject" : "Language" }
{ "_id" : 2, "student" : "A", "subject" : "Math" }
{ "_id" : 3, "student" : "B", "subject" : "Science" }
{ "_id" : 4, "student" : "A", "subject" : "Arts" }
{ "_id" : 5, "student" : "C", "subject" : "Biology" }
{ "_id" : 6, "student" : "B", "subject" : "History" }
```

**The Result After Each Stage:**

**1st Stage:** `$group`

```
{ "_id" : "C", "studentSubjects" : [ "Biology" ] }
{ "_id" : "B", "studentSubjects" : [ "History", "Science" ] }
{ "_id" : "A", "studentSubjects" : [ "Arts", "Math", "Language" ] }
```

**2nd Stage:** `$project`

```
{ "_id" : "C", "subjectMatches" : false }
{ "_id" : "B", "subjectMatches" : false }
{ "_id" : "A", "subjectMatches" : true }
```

**3rd Stage:** `$match`

```
{ "_id" : "A", "subjectMatches" : true }
```

**4th Stage:** `$project`

```
{ "matched_student" : "A" }
```

Comment: Thanks prasad logics seems to be good, but I am running the above pipeline in MongoDB compass and the aggregate is not able to identify the subject Math and Language, but it’s able to find other subjects. Is their a way where in I can directly send the value math and language instead of depending on studentSubjects: { $addToSet: "$subject" }. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I was able to try the above code successfully - both in `mongo shell` as well as Compass (version 1.19). Also, I am using MongoDB version 4.0. May be, you are using different field names (or different upper/lower case) for your collection. Please check again.

Comment: I checked everything even then I was not able to get math and language grouped to A. I wonder why. I am not able to group only math and language other subjects are grouping

Comment: I just now added to the answer what the result looks like after each stage of the aggregation pipeline. You can see how the data gets transformed to get the final expected result. That is aggregation pipeline in action!

Comment: Explanations is crystal clear, I don’t know what I’m missing but I’m not able to get the expected results. Anyhow thanks for the help.

Comment: Prasad, can we hard code math and language instead of using this studentSubjects: { $addToSet: "$subject" } In $group. I’m feeling it’s not getting picked up here.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just need some tweak to your aggregation pipeline:

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $group:
    {
      _id: '$Student', // Group students by name
      subjects: {
        $addToSet: '$Subject', // Push all the subjects they take uniquely into an array
      },
    },
  },
  {
    // Filter for students who only offer Language and Mathematics
    $match: { subjects: { $all: ['Language', 'Math'], $size: 2 } },
  },
];


db.students.aggregate(pipeline);
```

That should give an output array like this:

```
[
  { "_id" : studentName1 , "subjects" : [ "Language", "Math" ] },
  { "_id" : studentName2 , "subjects" : [ "Language", "Math" ] },
  ....
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer OTZ. I’m facing a bit challenge in getting the math and language subjects identified by sub: { $addToSet: '$sub'}
It’s grouping all the other subjects other than math and language. Is their a way where we can skip the $addToSet and manually give math and language. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Looking at the document samples you updated your question with, I think you are facing that challenge because the subjects field is actually identified as `Subject` in your documents and not `sub`, I would update my answer to reflect that. Please, do let me know if it works.